# PLSRegressor with VotingRegressor in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to setup VotingRegressor() to work with two models; PLS and SVR, but I get an error whenever I try to implement the PLS model. With SVR and any other model it works fine.

My code is as follows:

```
reg1 = cross_decomposition.PLSRegression()
reg2 = svm.SVR()
regr = VotingRegressor(estimators=[('gb', reg1), ('rf', reg2)])
regr.fit(training_features, training_outputs)
```

And the error I receive is as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\lesag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_voting.py", line 68, in _predict
    return np.asarray([est.predict(X) for est in self.estimators_]).T
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 1) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new thi SKLearn so I'm sure it's something quite obvious that I'm missing.

I've tried changing the syntax, as well as other models, and with all other models the voting regressor works fine.